# What is the exact screen width and height of a phone?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to make a website design relative to a phone's screen width and height. I do that like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: ...) and (max-height: ...) {...}
```

I want to get the numbers as perfect as possible, so if anyone knows what resolution a phone has, or any other device for that matter, please let me know.

Comment: One option is to just use percentages. width: 100%; and height:100%;

Comment: Mobile devices come in many different sizes and resolutions. My Galaxy S8+ supports six or seven different screen resolutions. There is no *one size for all*. Have you never seen more than one tablet or phone? There are literally hundreds of possibilities; we're certainly not going to build you a list of all of them here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question is impossible.

Comment: (you can begin with:) Choose 1 or 2 (horizontal) breakpoints that'll create 2 or 3 ranges of horizontal resolutions. Don't even think about the height except for (games and) the length of content you're making your users scroll through (that's a topic for the UX/webdesigner) EDIT: narrower is the device, taller is the page so height isn't relative to a phone's viewport

Answer (score 4):

Every phone is different. There is no standard.

To that end, your media queries should be designed with breakpoints in mind, not exact dimensions, to accommodate a wide range of devices in each of several categories. How exactly you do this is beyond the scope of this question, and too broad to be remotely adequately covered in a Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not answer obviously off-topic questions as it…oh wait

Comment: @CodyGray If you have an issue with someone's answer, please flag it for moderator attent... oh.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to target all phones with just one media query. I usually start using percentages and making it flexible from a width of 480 or lower. Higher than that I want some control and have multiple media set up.